Searching text in code blocks don't work
I've tried searching user:me a_function_I_used then it never returns the result. Any texts that are used in code format or ``` code blocks ``` are never searchable. Searching for other texts in my posts is still OK, only texts in code formatting can't be found
Note, that though it used to be possible in the past according to comments and answer in Search just code, that feature stopped working at some point since then, and now broken.
For example searching for user:me code:"GetDetailsOf" on SuperUser doesn't return any result but I did use it in this answer where there are multiple occurrences of that word. Similarly searching for user:me code:"ToLower" on StackOverflow also doesn't work despite having this answer

Similar (same?): Search results are incomplete

It seems that code search only works for entire words, where words are whitespace-separated strings.
Taking the example posts from the question:



Search term
Posts appear in results




verMagicNumber
✅


ExpandOnStart
✅


WScript
❌


WScript.Echo
✅


GetDetailsOf
❌


"shellfolder.GetDetailsOf(shellfile,"
✅



WScript.Echo worked without quotes, but shellfolder.GetDetailsOf(shellfile, needed quotes.
